# CsvHelper not parsing empty column for double

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

I'm using CsvHelper to parse my CSV files.
In my CSV i have a column which contains a double value, but the csv generation tool can create this as an empty field.

Example CSV

```
Name,Value,Date
Jim;1.23;20200901
John;;20200901
```

The Value field for Jim works fine, but when it reaches John with an empty value i get the below exception.

```
The conversion cannot be performed.
    Text: ''
    MemberType: System.Double
    TypeConverter: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.DoubleConverter'
An unexpected error occurred.
```

I cant find anything in the documentation. I want empty fields to default to 0.

My Code:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

In this case im running the below like `var result = ParseCsvZipArchiveEntry<Transaction>(zipArchiveEntry);`

```
private List<T> ParseCsvZipArchiveEntry<T>(ZipArchiveEntry zipArchiveEntry) where T : class
{
    string TempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    List<T> Result = null;

    try
    {
        zipArchiveEntry.ExtractToFile(TempFilePath, true);

        CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration Config = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Config.Delimiter = ";";

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(TempFilePath))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, Config))
        {
            Result = csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(File.Exists(TempFilePath))
            File.Delete(TempFilePath);
    }

    return Result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the `Default` attribute to the property in your model. It is advertised as [*The default value that will be used when reading when the CSV field is empty.*](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes/DefaultAttribute)

```
using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;

public class Transaction
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Default(0)]  // set to 0 when the field is empty
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

In my testing this returns the List of 2 Transaction instances where the second instance has a `Value` of 0.

[image]

The API documentation for that attribute is [found here](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes/DefaultAttribute).